# Passing state via this.history.pushState()

Tags: react-router

I'm using react-router 1.0 and their integration of history.

```jsx
import { createHistory, useBasename } from 'history'

const history = useBasename(createHistory)({
    basename: '/base-path'
});

export default (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={require("Template")}>
            <Route path="sub-page" component={require("SubPage")}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

I'm attempting to remove IDs from our API and in the URL and pass the self link create by [HATEOAS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) in a JSON object.
I would like to pass the data via the pushState state parameter.

```js
onClickEditButton(selfLinkObject) {
    this.history.pushState(selfLinkObject, "/my/url");
}
```

But when I attempt to get the state it's not being passed.

```jsx
import React from "react"
import { History } from "react-router"

export default React.createClass({
    mixins: [History],
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.state);
        console.log(this.history.state);
        console.log(history.state);
    },
    render() {
        <p>Check the console to see if the state is passed from the pushState(state, url, params);</p>
    }
});
```

It seems this is the way pushState was intended to work according to [Mozilla's pushState documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState%28%29_method) because the browser  saves state objects to the user's disk so they can be restored after the user restarts the browser.

Does any one know how or if I can pass data to the state or if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The state is on `location` so, you can access it via `props` if it's your route component: `this.props.location.state` or get the `location` object of the context.

Check out [Pinterest example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/v3/examples/pinterest) in the v3 docs, which is doing exactly what you want.

**edit:**
Here is the link to the example in React Router v4:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery

Comment: DUDE!!! This is EXACTLY what I need ... I thought I searched every part of the documentation. I really appreciate you man! You are a rockstar!!

Comment: glad I could help. if this is not clear in the docs, please send the PR with suggested changes.

Comment: Link no longer exists.

Comment: Dude, you're a rock!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Link exists again